# Files endpoint not working on Office 365 Unified API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

Here's the query that is failing:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/files
(It's also present in the Microsoft website here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The error message I am getting is:

```
Resource not found for the segment 'files'.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made an update to the API to align with the converged OneDrive API that works for both consumer and commercial users. More details here: http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-2-on-Office-365-unified-API